# Show that function is Lipschitz continuous at $ x = 0$

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions

Following function is given: $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if $x\ne 0$, and} \\
0 & \text{if $x=0$.}\end{cases}$$
Now we have to show, that this function is Lipschitz-continuous  at $x = 0$.

Following was our try, please let us know if there are any mistakes:

Let $x\ne 0$ and $y=0$.  Then
$$|f(y)-f(x)|=\left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \le |x| = |x-y|=1\cdot|x-y|$$

Therefore $L=1$ should be Lipschitz-constant and the function is locally continuous at $y=0$.

Is this right? 
Otherwise, we would be very happy about getting more useful hints.

Comment: Aside from being a little wordy, it looks fine to me.  I probably would have written $$|f(x) - f(0)| = \left| \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right| \le |x| \le |x-0|,$$ thereby demonstrating Lipschitz continuity at zero (with constant 1).

Comment: thank you very much !!! ;)

Comment: Lipschitz at a point !! I think the right terminology is calm at point.

Comment: @Redshoes "Lipschitz at a point" is commonly used.

Comment: Never heard that one tho